# An optimization problem, in the form of a word problem,

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, optimization, lagrange-multiplier

The manager of a $1000$ seat concert hall knows from experience that all seats will be occupied if the ticket price is $50$ dollars.  A market survey indicates that $10$ additional seats will remain empty for each $ \$5$ increase of the ticket price.  What is the ticket price which maximizes the manager's revenue?  How many seats will be occupied at that price?

My work, so far:

The possible scenarios are $50\times1000, 55\times990, 60\times980, \ldots$

Let $x =$ ticket price.

Let $y =$ number of tickets sold.

Clearly, $x$ and $y$ are $related$ variables.  So, I want to use the method of Lagrange multipliers.

Here are some difficulties, though: $$\text{revenue} = f(x,y) = xy$$

is not a vector valued function $-$ I want to compute the gradient of some vector-valued function, $f$, and solve $$\nabla(f) = \lambda \nabla(g).$$

And moreover, what would the constraint function, $g$, even be?

I can think of two constraints:

$$\max(y) = 1000 \text{ tickets}$$

and $$\min(x) = 50 \text{ dollars}$$

I would like hints only for now.

Thanks,

Comment: This is fundamentally a $1$ variable problem. Increase the ticket price by $x$ increments of $5$ dollars. Then the number of occupied seats is $1000-10x$. Now you can calculate the income $f(x)$ and maximize as usual.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I pointed out in a comment, the problem is quite simply solved using one-variable techniques.

However, let us explore your choice of letting $x$ be the ticket price and $y$ the number of tickets sold. Then the number of $5$ dollar increments is $\frac{x-50}{5}$. The resulting number $y$ of tickets sold  is given by 
$$y=1000-10\cdot \frac{x-50}{5}.$$ This is the constraint, which you may wish to simplify.  (There is also the implicit $y\le 1000$.) Now we can use the Lagrange multiplier machinery.

Comment: Hi @AndreNicolas, first off, thanks so much for the clever suggestion - to turn the problem into a one variable problem, with the variable being the *number* of price increments *instead* of the ticket price or tickets sold.  I couldn't have thought of that myself and would have still kept trying to set up a two-variable, related variable problem for awhile.  I think I have my correct revenue = f(x) set up, I used the usual calculus methods and I'm confident that I have solved it.  However, I tried for a long time last night - and now today - to try to use the Lagrange multiplier method,

Comment: using the constraint as you've suggested.  However, my equations don't make sense:  if my f(x,y) = xy gives grad(f) = (y,x) and y=g(x) gives grad(g) = (-2x,0), i get x = 0, which is nonsense.  I then thought perhaps I should use some form of implicit differentiation, so I let grad(g) = (-2x, 1).  the resulting equations are also nonsensical.  I get something like 1,100 = 0.

Comment: Where am I going wrong, in trying to set this problem up as a two-variable  problem, @andrenicolas?  Thanks,

Comment: (in the one-variable setting, my f(x) = (50+5x)(1,000-10x).)

Comment: I set it up for Lagrange multipliers, since that's what you asked for.  The constraint simplifies to $2x+y-1100=0$. So we are looking at $xy-\lambda(2x+y-1100)$. Taking partial with respect to $x$, and setting equal to $0$, we get $y-2\lambda=0$. Similarly, $x-\lambda=0$. So $y=2x$. Substitute in $2x+y-1100=0$. We get $x=275$, $y=550$. But as I said, it is easier as a standard first year calculus $1$ variable problem.

Comment: sorry, i meant grad(g) = (-2$\lambda$,0) *or*(-2$\lambda$,1) ...

Comment: In the one variable version where $x$ is the number of $5$ dollar increments, we get after simplification $f(x)=50(1000+90x-x^2)$. Differentiate, set the derivative equal to $0$. We get $x=45$, so the price is $50+5(45)=275$ per ticket.

Comment: Hi @AndreNicolas, ah, I see now - I had not set up my constraint correctly; I needed it in the form of a level curve, g(x,y) = c.  Can I ask you one more question regarding this problem?  The one-variable setting seems like the better way for yet another important reason:  the second derivative at the one (and only) critical point is negative, which assures us that a (the?) maximum revenue is attained at x = 45.  In contrast,  with lagrange multiplies, we get x = 275 (ticket price), y = 550 simply enough, if the problem is set up correctly.  However, we're usually taught that these x, y values

Comment: are values to be *tested* in the function f(x,y), and we pick the values of x,y that give us the highest values of f(x,y).  since we only have *one* value of each of x and y, how do we conclude these points are indeed where f(x,y) attains a maximum?

Comment: It is enough to look at the behaviour of the first derivative. The second derivative test is easy here, but often it is not. There are similar techniques available when we are using Lagrange multipliers, but admittedly they are more complicated.  Often there is no need for such techniques. From the shape of the problem it may be clear that there *is* a max, or that there is a min, If we have only one candidate, we know what it is.

Comment: Ok, got it.  Thanks so much, @AndreNicolas.  I am very happy to have understood this problem now in both the one-dimensional and two-dimensional settings.  In the past, I have heard of tricky implicit function theorem questions that are in one-dimensional settings, too.  Now I will hopefully be ready to recognize these questions sooner :-)  Have a great day.

Comment: You are welcome.